# Generate random number and search database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am looking for some assistance to create a php script to do the following please?

1. Generate a random number between 1 and 100 so lets say 50 is the number that has been generated (I know how to do this)
2. Search database for the id #50 (I know how to do this)
3. Return the value of a column named "status" of row 50 which will be either 1 or zero (I know how to do this)
4. if status = zero then do something and exit but if status = 1 then i need to go back to step 1 and keep doing this until status = 0 (This is the bit I am stuck on)

My PHP Version is 5.4.45 & MySQLI is 5.6.37

Any help would be greatly appreciated. many thanks in advance for your help.

Richard

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from t where status=0 order by rand() limit 1;
```

this is the easiest way to select a random row from mysql

Comment: Hi and thank you for your speedy response which provide a very simple way to acheive what I was looking to do.

Comment: So my next step is once i have retrieved the data I require I run:

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE $db_table_10 SET status = 1 WHERE id = '$testid'";

Comment: I then run the query again but now I have no status values that equal zero as they are all now 1. So I need to set all the status values to zero and then start process all over again. How would you recommend doing this part please? Thanks again.

Comment: update t set status =0; it will rest all of them back to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
update t set status =0;  it will set all the cords back to 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should produce the behavior you are looking for...

```
while (true)
{
    $num = rand(1,100);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $num); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt_result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($stmt_result->num_rows == 0)
    {
        $stmt->close();
        continue;
    }

    $status = null;

    while ($row = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $status = $row['status'];
    }

    $stmt->close();

    if (status == 0)
    {
        DoSomething();
        break;
    }
}
```